# display:none doesn't work on Outlook 2007

Tags: css, outlook

I want to send an e-mail from our system to customers, where some tags should be hidden to them. I've set the following CSS:

```
.hidden { display: none; }
```

But this does not work. What solutions or alternatives are there for hiding elements in an e-mail?

Comment: This is not really an answer but you should see this: [http://www.email-standards.org/clients/microsoft-outlook-2007/](http://www.email-standards.org/clients/microsoft-outlook-2007/) This is why `display: none` and a lot of other things do not work on outlook 2007.

Comment: sucks as an alt but we could try pointer-events:none; and visibility:hidden;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Outlook 2007 uses the Microsoft Word engine for rendering HTML which has *very limited* support for CSS. [This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201.aspx) describes the kind of things you can expect to work (`display` is one of the "not supported" ones).

Unfortunately, there's not much you can do. You can enclose the element in HTML comments `<!-- ... -->` which would stop it from rendering, but that's about it.

Comment: This answer seems inaccurate according to the linked document. It lists `display` as supported for everything with CORE or better. A `<div>`, for example, is listed as COREEXTENDED.

Comment: My mistake, it lists `display` as a supported property in one spot and unsupported in another.

Comment: you are right. i also found this in this document:http://www.inxmail.com/en_PDFs/inxmail_guide_outlook2007.pdf
it says: The CSS property display is no longer supported by Outlook 2007. To implement the various 2007
display types, it is necessary to use table layouts or the corresponding HTML tags.

Comment: I hate to up vote this, but this is still the case in Outlook 2016. Amazing how Microsoft in general refuses to follow web standards.

Answer (score 25):

Use `mso-hide:all` in a span surrounding the content, and on any other tags within the span.

Comment: I spent hours looking for this answer!

Comment: This is still valid for outlook 2013 on windows

Comment: This worked for me using style="mso-hide:all; display:none; max-height:0px; overflow:hidden;"

Answer (score 15):

The only working solution I've found is to use conditional formatting in the HTML source :

```
<!--[if !mso 9]><!-->
<div>This block of code will display <b>everywhere</b> except in Outlook 2007.</div>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Comment: This works well but triggers new problems with Windows Phone.  I actually use this method in my emails currently but on Windows Phone it prints the characters --> on the end of the conditional and displays as a block element pushing everything down.  The reason being is that <!--[if !mso9]><!--> is not proper conditional syntax but Outlook actually requires the improper syntax for it to work.  In Windows Phone, it's not a huge problem but it does ruin the horizontal alignment of banners at the top and bottom of my emails.  I'm currently looking for a fix for that.

Answer (score 9):

I did some quick testing, and found that Outlook (2000, 2003, 2007, 2010, 2013 and Outlook.com) supported several variations of `display: none;` as expected. On the other hand, Gmail in the browser and on Android failed miserably.

**I tested the following:**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="display: none;">01</td>
    <td style="display: none !important;">02</td>
    <td style="display: none; display: none !important;">03</td>
    <td id="displayNone">04</td> 
    <td id="displayNoneImportant">05</td>
    <td id="displayNoneDisplayNoneImportant">06</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS inline, in the HEAD and in the BODY**

Where there are IDs, I tested the follow CSS in the HEAD of one email and in the BODY of another email.

```
<style>
    #displayNone {
        display: none;
    }
    #displayNoneImportant {
        display: none !important;
    }
    #displayNoneDisplayNoneImportant {
        display: none;
        display: none !important;
    }
</style>
```

**RESULTS: CSS Inline and in the BODY**

1. Outlook (all) passed; Outlook.com Android failed, Gmail (all) failed
2. Outlook (all) passed; Gmail (all) failed
3. Outlook (all) passed; Gmail (all) failed
4. Outlook (all) passed; Gmail (all) failed
5. Outlook 2007, 2010 & 2013 failed; Gmail (all) failed
6. Outlook (all) passed; Gmail (all) failed

Outlook (all) = 2000, 2003, 2007, 2010, 2013, Android Outlook, Outlook.com (IE, Fx, Chrome)

Gmail (all) = Gmail in IE, Fx, Chrome and in Android

**RESULTS: CSS Inline and in the HEAD**

1. Outlook (all) passed; Outlook.com Android failed; Gmail (all) failed
2. Outlook (all) passed; Outlook.com Android failed; Gmail (all) failed
3. Outlook (all) passed; Outlook.com Android failed; Gmail (all) failed
4. Outlook (all) passed; Outlook.com Android failed; Gmail (all) failed
5. Outlook 2007, 2010 & 2013 failed; Outlook.com Android failed; Gmail (all) failed
6. Outlook (all) passed; Outlook.com Android failed; Gmail (all) failed

**LONG STORY SHORT**

Outlook 2000+ supports `display: none;` fairly well.  Gmail does not.  It became difficult to discern what was failing or working in Gmail due to how much it failed.  The screens even became cropped in certain situations.

I'll retest later and post screenshots if I can — right now my testing set up is taking too long to save out screen shots of each scenario and reader.

Comment: Maybe the results were different when you tested in 2013... As of writing this comment in 2022, Gmail does support display: none, but it does not support classes. As such, to use display: none with Gmail, you have to use inlined style.

Answer (score 2):

Outlook 2007 has limited support for CSS and HTML. Read [this article](http://css-tricks.com/using-css-in-html-emails-the-real-story/) for more information.

If class-based CSS rules don't work, try ID-based CSS rules. Just try to keep your rules as simple as possible.

You can use [this tool](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=0b764c08-0f86-431e-8bd5-ef0e9ce26a3a&displaylang=en) to validate your HTML and CSS for use in Outlook 2007.

Answer (score 2):

Late, but, as general guidelines for e-mails:

1) Always use tables

2) Don't use following tags: div, p, i, or b (use em for italic, and strong for bolding.

3) Don't set font properties on body tag, or even on parent elements like table tags; you must set the font properties on every area where there is text displayed; however, you CAN set it on a tr tag instead of on each td tag. Just remember to do it on EVERY tr that has text displayed in its subsequent td's, unless the text is wrapped inside another or several other elements/tags.

4) Put "mso-hide:all;" as an INLINE style on parent element as well as the child elements. You can also try setting width and height to 1px (setting to 0 rarely works for many clients) and then set visibility to "hidden" and just in case, set opacity to ".0" or "0", just to cover your bases.

5) Do not use non-breaking space elements in empty td's where you're using them to create padding (which is better than using CSS padding in most cases). The nbsp element will force heights to be incapable of being less than a certain size, which is annoying when you're trying to create, say, a 2px vertacle spacing.

5) Using the "if lt mso9" trick works well, but avoid using it to "hide" things in desktop view & displaying them on mobile. It's less elegant and it also creates bloated code. Use the above method(s) instead if you can, if for nothing else, for future version compatibilty's sake.

Answer (score 2):

```
<p style="color:#ffffff;width:0px;height:0px;display:none"> 
<!--[if !mso]><!-->
<p style="color:#ffffff;width:0px;height:0px;display:none !important;">
<!--<![endif]-->
I am not showing !!!
</p>
```

This works for me !

Answer (score 1):

You can try to wrap around

```
     <!--[if !IE]><!-->


     <!--<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit too late but you can try for example:

```
<span style="font-size: 0px; color: White; display: none">Yada Yada</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution was tested on Outlook 2007 and works.

```
< td style="line-height:0; border:0; font-size:0px" >
```

Answer (score 0):

how about remove the tags with "display:none;" with code. 
i use string.split the html string `String.split("<td ")` and `StringBuilder sb`. 
then if-else. if the split string does not `.contains("display:none;")` then append to stringbuilder `sb.append(String)`. make sure to put back the `"<td "` , so `sb.append("<td " + String)`. u might want to exclude several split string, such as null split string,or which contains tags(`"<h1 "`,`"<table "` ).

Answer (score -2):

Try this — maybe it will work for you.

```
.hidden{visibility: hidden;}
```

Comment: Also you can try 

.hidden{width: 0px; height:0px;}

Comment: Did you actually try this or is it just a random guess? CSS styles won't work.