# how to get round outlook ignoring display:none

Tags: html, email, outlook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [display:none doesn’t work on Outlook 2007](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719216/displaynone-doesnt-work-on-outlook-2007)

hi i'm creating an html email that i'm wanting to show and hide certain elements based on screen size for example one button for desktop one button for mobile. now it works in everything except outlook 2007 and above in which it shows both images. Does anyone know why? and/or how to get round this?

Comment: Wouldn't this be a security concern? What would stop you embedding malicious content into the email and then setting it's display:none.

Comment: Did you try setting the **width** and **height** equal to 0?

Comment: its a fair point about the security although i can say that i would never do such a thing i love what i do and i do it with honesty. just trying to create new and creative things that push our industry forward