# "list-style-type: none" does not work in Outlook 2007

Tags: css, email, outlook, outlook-2007, newsletter

"list-style-type: none" does not work in Outlook 2007

I programmed an e-mail newsletter with html.
I am able to change the display of list items with list-style-type.
E.g. if I write

```
ul{ list-style-type: square;}
```

the list items are displayed with a square (in Outlook 2007 and Thunderbird 32).

However if I write

```
ul{ list-style-type: none;}
```

Outlook 2007 shows the standards circles while Thunderbird shows nothing as it should.

Helpful, but not resolving links:

- [display:none doesn't work on Outlook 2007](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719216/displaynone-doesnt-work-on-outlook-2007)
- https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you can read here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201.aspx "none" isn't working. But you could fake a list with a table. Or, as you don't want any list-type, just do line-breaks.

Comment: Where did you read this? I only found them saying that "list-style-type" is part of the CORE elements which are supported.

Comment: There is one heading "Unsupported Cascading Style Sheet Properties Compared with Cascading Style Sheets, Level 1" where they state what Word cannot do. And as Outlook uses Words Renderer to display HTML you can't use those things. One of those is "display" which you need to use the "none" attribute.

Comment: 2021 and it is still not supported, wtf Microsoft? I think Outlook has Corona

Comment: @Andi `list-style-type` is not mentioned in that paragraph "Unsupported Cascading Style Sheet Properties Compared with Cascading Style Sheets, Level 1" which you refer to. So I still don't get why it would not be supported...